# How to use the custom fonts in M2 using LESS

Tags: magento2.3, frontend, less, design, custom-theme

I am new to magento2, so I don't understand the less flow in M2, how it is working, and how to use the custom fonts in my theme which is present in the /fonts dir when I import the fonts using @font-face on the .css file it is working fine but when I use the @font-face code (which was used in the .css file), in .module.less it's not working I don't understand why it's not working can you help me to understand **How to use the custom fonts using .less**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/web/css/source/_typography.less**

```less
@font-path: "../fonts/";

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    src: url('@{font-path}montserrat-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('@{font-path}montserrat-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}
```

See also [Using custom fonts](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/using-fonts.html)

Comment: Thanks, victor Tihonchuk, not it working fine and I understand how to use the custom fonts in Magento 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can override default magento file from vendor and place in below file.

if you want to add new font family you can place in  app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/web/font/<font_family_name>/<font_family_files>(.ttf/woff)

app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/web/css/source/_typography.less

```
.lib-font-face(
    @family-name: @font-family-name__base,
    @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/latolatin/LatoLatin-Regular',
    @font-weight: 400,
    @font-style: normal,
    @font-display: swap
);
```

in vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/web/css/source/_variables.less, we can mention variables like:-
@font-family-name__base: 'Open Sans';